# Reduce Grid visibility in Windows Form Chart

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi i am using Bar chart in windows form application . It shows line grid behind bar area my client wants two changes 1: change grid from line to dotted view and grid style should be dark grey shade . Can you please give your suggestions?

```
 var chart = new Chart
        {
            Width = 500,
            Height = 360,
            AntiAliasing = AntiAliasingStyles.All,
            TextAntiAliasingQuality = TextAntiAliasingQuality.High
        };
chart.Series.Add("");
        foreach (String description in keyValue.Keys)
        {`enter code here`
            decimal value;
            keyValue.TryGetValue(description, out value);                
            chart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(description, value);                 
        }
chart.Series[0].Font = new Font(Constant.FontFamily, 15f, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);
        chart.Series[0].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Bar;
        chart.Series[0].Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(169, 14, 59);
chart.ChartAreas.Add("CharArea");
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = new Font(Constant.FontFamily,15);
        chart.Legends.Add(new Legend());
        chart.Legends[0].Enabled = false;
 chart.Series[0].CustomProperties = "DrawingStyle=Cylinder";
       // chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = new Font(Constant.FontFamily, 9f, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);

        using (var chartimage = new MemoryStream())
        {
            chart.SaveImage(chartimage, ChartImageFormat.Png);
            return chartimage.GetBuffer();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to the end of your .FromArgb method 0,0

Overall it will look like .FromArgb(r, g, b, 0, 0)

Comment: well i tried following code and it worked for me:   chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.DashDotDot;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.DashDotDot;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.DarkGray;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.DarkGray;

Answer (score 0):

I did following changes in my code and it worked for me. For dotted line and grey color

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.DashDotDot;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.DashDotDot;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.DarkGray;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.DarkGray;
```